# FactoryGirl: let! doesn't create object automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

For example I have the following defined object using `FactoryGirl`

```
let!(:product_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
let!(:product_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
let!(:product_uom_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:product_uom, :store_order_unit, product: product_1) }
let!(:product_uom_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:product_uom, :store_order_unit, product: product_2) }

let!(:purchase_order_detail_1) {
  FactoryGirl.create(:purchase_order_detail, :default_return_quantity,
                     product: product_1,
                     purchase_order: purchase_order,
                     order_quantity: 100)
}
```

Above code will run fail because at the time create `purchase_order_detail`, `product_uom_1` and `product_uom_2` haven't been created yet. (It will make some of my later code fail). But If I call those objects "manually":

```
let!(:purchase_order_detail_1) {
  product_uom_1
  product_uom_2
  FactoryGirl.create(:purchase_order_detail, :default_return_quantity,
                     product: product_1,
                     purchase_order: purchase_order,
                     order_quantity: 100)
}
```

The difference here is I just simply print it out. And then `product_uom_1` and `product_uom_2` will be created before create `purchase_order_detail`. I don't know why because I have used `let!`. Please explain for me how to fix and not use this "trick" because it makes my spec ugly.

Comment: In your sample code, I don't see any relationship between `purchase_order_detail`, `product_uom_1` and `product_uom_2`. Show the code where you define `purchase_order_detail` factory.

Comment: `FactoryGirl` is deprecated. Please follow this guide: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md